# How can I move along a line (or path)?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, line, route

Given a line (street, railroad, river...) I want to simulate a moviment inside this line.

Example:

See this picture:

[image]

Say I'm in "Nagqu" and want to move to "Kunlunqial".
In a time (t=0) I'm in Nagqu. By flowing the time, my point moves a little to northeast (lets say a velocity of 40MPH). In this time (t=1) I want a point exactly inside the railroad.

I know how to trace a straight line from a point to anohter, but I need to stay in the railroad (or line) no matter where it goes to. I need to find a point in that line until I reach my destination.

In other words: find a point inside a line given a direction (a line have only 2 directions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html). The function takes as an argument a fraction of length so your formula will be roughly:

```
SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(geom,LEAST(1.0,(:v*:t)/ST_Length(geom))
FROM table;
```

`LEAST` is there to prevent us from going higher than 1.0 if v*t>length.

If your source data is a single linestring from Lhasa all the way to Xining you can use [ST_Line_Locate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html) to get the start and end locations.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this ASAP and publish here if satisfy my needs. I will consider I need the WHERE to find my line in table "table"... is this correct?

Comment: Oh yes, you need WHERE clause and your own logic to determine what line you need by selecting it by id or by being near those two cities. I just gave you the names of the functions that do what you want.

Comment: Well, seems to be what I need, but I don't understood the `:v * :t` part ... I think it's `velocity * time` but not work. `SELECT ST_Length(the_geom) as length,
 ST_AsText ( ST_StartPoint(the_geom) ) as start,
 ST_AsText ( ST_EndPoint(the_geom) ) as end,
 ST_AsText(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point( the_geom, LEAST( 1.0, ( 10 * 2 ) / ST_Length(the_geom) ) ) ) as now FROM routes where id = 1` returns always the end of line, since ST_Line_Interpolate_Point needs a percent of total of the line. My line length is 2.26, V=10 T=2 : (10*2) / 2.26 = 8.84 ( it's > 1.0 )

Comment: My mistake: ST_Length must be a Geography to work: `ST_Length( Geography( the_geom ) ) as length`

Comment: `ST_Length` does work for geometry, your problem is with units. The manual states `Geometry: Measurements are in the units of the spatial reference system of the geometry. Geography: Units are in meters` Converting the geom to geography is a pretty clever solution though it might be a source of performance issues.

Comment: You did it !!! Works like a charm !  :v * :t is in meters, just what I need.