# Following path in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, mapping

I want to visualize a road present in the OpenStreetMap.

Using OpenLayers, I try to do in the following way:

1. Take a set of co-ordinates which should represent the two sides of the road.
2. Join both the points on the map. (leads to a straight line)

Now, the problem with this approach is that it is just a straight line (obviously), what is the way of following the path along the road ?

Just a note that I'm not tied up with OpenLayers or anything. I can use any mapping library as long as it achieves this functionality.

Comment: Try this:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75624/how-can-i-move-along-a-line-or-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) directly read OpenStreetMap vector files (.osm format) and [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) can read it with [plugin](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/leaflet-osm). Osm file contains all the points of the road in order.

Answer (score 4):

If you like to avoid the .OSM file, you can also use the Overpass API to get live data: http://www.overpass-api.de/open_layers_mashup.html